# Numpy running at half the speed of MATLAB

Tags: python, performance, matlab, numpy, atlas

I've been porting MATLAB code over to Python and, after quite a lot of work, I have stuff that works. The downside, however, is that Python is running my code more slowly than MATLAB did. I understand that using optimised ATLAS libraries will speed things up, but actually implementing this is confusing me. Here's what's going on:

I start an ipython session with no BLAS installed:

```
import numpy.distutils.system_info as sysinfo
import time
In [11]: sysinfo.get_info('atlas')
Out[11]: {}

timeit( eig(randn(1E2,1E2)) )
100 loops, best of 3: 13.4 ms per loop
```

The same code in Matlab runs twice as fast

```
tic,eig(randn(1E2));toc*1000
    6.5650
```

I install the non-optimised ATAS deb from the Ubuntu repository. Re-start ipython and now I get:

```
In [2]: sysinfo.get_info('atlas')
 ...
Out[2]: 
{'define_macros': [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')],
 'include_dirs': ['/usr/include/atlas'],
 'language': 'f77',
 'libraries': ['lapack', 'f77blas', 'cblas', 'atlas'],
 'library_dirs': ['/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas', '/usr/lib/atlas-base']}
```

And the test code:

```
In [4]: timeit( eig(randn(1E2,1E2)) )
100 loops, best of 3: 16.8 ms per loop
```

So no faster. If anything a touch slower. But I haven't yet switched to the optimised BLAS. I follow these instructions: http://danielnouri.org/notes/category/python/ I build the libraries and overwrite the non-optimised versions with these. I re-start ipython but there's no change:

```
In [4]: timeit( eig(randn(1E2,1E2)) )
100 loops, best of 3: 15.3 ms per loop
```

Can't it get better than this? MATLAB is still twice as fast in this simple example. In a real-world example where I'm doing image registration in the Fourier domain, the Matlab equivalent is 4 to 5 times faster than the Python version. Has anyone managed to get Numpy working at MATLAB speeds?

Comment: With a good BLAS library, it's essentially identical in speed. Building ATLAS correctly for your architecture can be a pain. Try using something like EPD (now Canopy) and see if you have similar speed issues.  However, there's still one big wrinkle when dealing with eigenvectors. Matlab checks whether the data you're working on is symmetric and uses a different algorithm in that case. In numpy, you'll need to explicitly use `eigh` instead of `eig` to get the same speed with a symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Simple example

Numpy is calculating both the eigenvectors and eigenvalues, so it will take roughly twice longer, which is consistent with your slowdown (use `np.linalg.eigvals` to compute only the eigenvalues).

In the end, `np.linalg.eig` is a tiny wrapper around dgeev, and likely the same thing happens in Matlab, which is using MKL.

To get virtually the same speed in linear algebra, you could build Numpy against MKL or OpenBLAS. There are some commercial offers (maybe free for academics) from [Continuum](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/accelerate) or [Enthought](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/faq/). You could also get MKL and build Numpy [yourself](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/numpy-scipy-with-mkl).

### Real-world example

4x slower seems like too much (I have rewritten some Matlab code in Numpy and both programs performed in a very similar way). Take into account that recent Matlab versions come with a simple JIT, so loops aren't as bad as in the usual Python implementation. If you're doing many FFT, you could benefit from using a [FFTW wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365623/improving-fft-performance-in-python) ([pyFFTW](http://hgomersall.github.io/pyFFTW/) seems nice, but I haven't used it).

Comment: Ah, yes, it's true. If I ask for both eigenvectors and eigenvalues then it's the same speed in Matlab. Thanks for pointing that out. What's really been killing me, though is the FFT. In MATLAB: `tic, fft2(rand(1024)); toc` is 25 ms but in Python the same thing is 125 ms. Am I again, like with `eig`, missing something basic about how Python is doing the 2D FFT?

Comment: @user2307841 Yep, I was now writing about FFT just in case, see the edit.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at those FFT routines. My core code involves no loops. I'm doing image registration and about 4 FFTs per image pair. But eventually I will need to run many image pairs (hundreds) and there the decrease in speed will be obvious and annoying. I must say, I'm surprised the stock Numpy routines are this much slower than MATLAB.

Comment: @user2307841 Absolutely. Getting fast linear algebra is somewhat easy (just get EPD etc) but getting a really FFT is probably trickier than it should. The reason is simple, though: FFTW is GPL, not compatible with the BSD license in Numpy. Once you get it all working, it's a joy (and the only language where you can `import antigravity`).