# MATLAB twice as fast as Numpy

Tags: python, performance, matlab, numpy, intel-mkl

I am an engineering grad student currently making the transition from MATLAB to Python for the purposes of numerical simulation. I was under the impression that for basic array manipulation, Numpy would be as fast as MATLAB. However, it appears for two different programs I write that MATLAB is a little under twice as fast as Numpy. The test code I am using for Numpy (Python 3.3) is:

```
import numpy as np
import time

a = np.random.rand(5000,5000,3)

tic = time.time()
a[:,:,0] = a[:,:,1]
a[:,:,2] = a[:,:,0]
a[:,:,1] = a[:,:,2]
toc = time.time() - tic
print(toc)
```

Whereas for MATLAB 2012a I am using:

```
a = rand(5000,5000,3);

tic;
a(:,:,1) = a(:,:,2);
a(:,:,3) = a(:,:,1);
a(:,:,2) = a(:,:,3);
toc
```

The algorithm I am using is the one used on a NASA [website](https://modelingguru.nasa.gov/docs/DOC-1762) comparing Numpy and MATLAB. The website shows that Numpy surpasses MATLAB in terms of speed for this algorithm. Yet my results show a 0.49 s simulation time for Numpy and a 0.29 s simulation time for MATLAB. I also have run a Gauss-Seidel solver on both Numpy and Matlab and I get similar results (16.5 s vs. 9.5 s)

I am brand new to Python and am not extremely literate in terms of programming. I am using the WinPython 64 bit Python distribution but have also tried Pythonxy to no avail.

One thing I have read which should improve performance is building Numpy using MKL. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this on Windows. Do I even need to do this?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Christoph Gohlke provides precompiled Windows binaries for many Python packages, with NumPy linked against Intel MKL: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Yep. Python used to be even slower relative to Matlab so you're lucky. :-)

Comment: The current distribution of WinPython [already comes with NumPy-MKL](https://code.google.com/p/winpython/wiki/PackageIndex_33).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

That comparison ends up being apples to oranges due to caching, because it is more efficient to transfer or do some work on contiguous chunks of memory. This particular benchmark is memory bound, since in fact no computation is done, and thus the percentage of cache hits is key to achieve good performance.

Matlab lays the data in column-major order (Fortran order), so `a(:,:,k)` is a contiguous chunk of memory, which is fast to copy.

Numpy defaults to row-major order (C order), so in `a[:,:,k]` there are big jumps between elements and that slows down the memory transfer. Actually, the data layout can be chosen. In my laptop, creating the array with `a = np.asfortranarray(np.random.rand(5000,5000,3))` leds to a 5x speed up (1 s vs 0.19 s).

This result should be very similar both for numpy-MKL and plain numpy because MKL is a fast LAPACK implementation and here you're not calling any function that uses it (MKL definitely helps when solving linear systems, computing dot products...).

I don't really know what's going on on the Gauss Seidel solver, but some time ago I wrote an answer to a question titled [Numpy running at half the speed of MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178471/numpy-running-at-half-the-speed-of-matlab) that talks a little bit about MKL, FFT and Matlab's JIT.

Comment: I just noticed this was downvoted (that's a first for me). Any comments on how to improve the answer?

Comment: Ok, I tried your suggestion using the different array construction and it also led to a ~5x speedup in Numpy which is great. I tried this suggestion with my Gauss-Seidel solver and it offered no improvement suggesting there is another problem. I am not using any fancy functions or anything in this solver, it is pretty much just a while loop with about 16 lines of vectorized assignments and a couple control statements. What you wrote in the old topic also does not help me. Is there any way I could send you my code to inspect, or maybe ask it in a new question?

Comment: Since the problem seems to be different, you can of course ask another question so that more people may benefit from it!

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to recreate the NASA experiment, however you have changed many of the variables. For example:

- Your hardware and operating system is different ([www.nccs.nasa.gov/dali_front.html](http://www.nccs.nasa.gov/dali_front.html))
- Your Python version is different (2.5.3 vs 3.3)
- Your MATLAB version is different (2008 vs 2012)

Assuming the NASA results are correct, the difference in results is due to one or more of these changed variables.  I recommend you:

- Retest with the SciPy prebuilt [binaries](https://web.archive.org/web/20150709091957/http://wiki.scipy.org:80/Installing_SciPy).
- Research if any improvements were made to [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html) relative to this type of calculation.

Also, you may find [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users) useful.

Comment: I had initially tried to compare to the NASA study, however, I was asking mostly to see if there was something I could do (or something obvious) which may cause Numpy to be twice as slow. If the answer was that the version of MATLAB I was using was just faster, then that's all I would have needed. Thanks, though.