# Vectorizing operation in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Is there a general way to vectorize these kind of operations in NumPy?

```
In [2]: N = 8

In [3]: ll = np.arange(8)

In [4]: arr = np.zeros(ll.shape + (2, 2))

In [5]: ll.shape
Out[5]: (8,)

In [6]: arr.shape
Out[6]: (8, 2, 2)

In [7]: for ii in range(N):
   ...:     arr[ii, :, :] = np.array(...)  # 2 x 2 array function of ll[ii]
```

if that function is a linear operation on ll then this would be trivial, but is there a way to do it in the general case? Just to put an example:

```
In [8]: for ii in range(N):
   ...:     arr[ii, :, :] = np.array([
   ...:         [np.cos(ll[ii]) - 1, 0],
   ...:         [np.sin(ll[ii]), np.cos(ll[ii]) ** 2]
   ...:     ])
```

Answer (score 5):

The right way of assembling your `arr` array would be something like:

```
arr[:, 0, 0] = np.cos(ll) - 1
arr[:, 0, 1] = 0
arr[:, 1, 0] = np.sin(ll)
arr[:, 1, 1] = np.cos(ll) ** 2
```

You definitely shouldn't call `np.array` on a list of arrays that are going to be stored in an already existing array: it's wasteful intermediate array creation, which is a bad practice, and I doubt it adds any clarity to the code. A memory/performance conscious developer would probably do something like:

```
np.cos(ll, out=arr[:, 0, 0])
arr[:, 1, 1] = arr[:, 0, 0]
arr[:, 0, 0] -= 1
arr[:, 0, 1] = 0
np.sin(ll, out=arr[:, 1, 0])
arr[:, 1, 1] *= arr[:, 1, 1]
```

But this would fall under the premature optimization category more often than not.

You should also really not use `ll` as a variable name...

Comment: I expected some way of vectorizing the whole thing in a one liner, but now that you bring up the performance thing I might do some benchmarks with the solutions you suggest. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to take a look at the comment thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580666/improving-numpy-speed-for-gauss-seidel-jacobi-solver/17581581?noredirect=1#comment25611917_17581581). I am not sure what's going on, but it seems that using the `out` argument of ufuncs does not consistently perform better. Very weird. Oh, and your blog, *muy chulo, enhorabuena* (very nice, congrats).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
def func(x):
    return np.array([
        [np.cos(x)-1,np.repeat(0, len(x))],
        [np.sin(x), np.cos(x)**2]
    ])
```

Then `func(x)` will return an array of shape `(2, 2, 8)`.  You can get it in the orientation you want with `func(x).T`.

This only works when `x` is one-dimensional.  I think you could work something out for higher dimensions using `np.broadcast_arrays`, but not sure exactly how at the moment.  The basic thing, though, is that if you want to return an array, you can't use vectorized numpy functions like `cos` in some cells, while putting literal scalars (like 0) in other cells.  You need to fill the scalar cells with an array whose shape is derived from the input array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I saw that the correct way to transpose it would be `arr.transpose(2, 0, 1)`. I am going to wait for other answers in case there is a clearer method, otherwise I will accept this.